# Purpose of throwing exception by Spring controller function

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have come across few Spring contoller's function, which are throwing IOException.

```
@RequestMapping(method = ***)
@ResponseBody
public List<Offering> getOfferingDetailsList(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("productIds") String productIdString, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
```

I doubt about use of such exception throwing, when no one above is catching and handling it.
 Is it fine to set response status like "response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND)" in place of throwing such exception ? 
What is the standard way of handling exception in controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is always good to have common exception handling functionality , so that we can make our controller code free from exception handling , by externalize to common exception handling functionality, i have come across this interesting topic for this purpose

http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

and also use a global exception handler that will do that for all the exceptions of all the controller methods. That will centralize the exception handling, prevent massive code duplication, and avoid cluttering your controller methods.

Look at the `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` annotations.

Comment: It is a new thing for me :). will like to try this out. thx pappu

Answer (score 1):

A fairly standard way of handling exceptions in Spring Controllers is to use @ExceptionHandler.

Check out [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exceptionhandler-example/) post for more details